# Linear regression and plots through each numerical independent variable and target variable

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, linear-regression

I would like to know is there a way where can I get one on one( 1 independent variable vs target variable) linear regression analysis ,its p value, R2 value and the plot to show how linearly it is related or not. And I want this to run on all independent variables separately. As far as I know it is possible to get OLS regression analysis from Python statsmodel library. It runs on whole dataset and give the result, and there are no plots to understand it visually.

Comment: This is interesting but [asking for package recommendations is offtopic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Best if you can explain which ones you tried and why they don't do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To very quickly visualize the regression you can try the below using sns:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=['sepal.length','sepal.width','petal.length','petal.width'])
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars='sepal.length')
df[:5]

sepal.length    variable    value
0   5.1 sepal.width 3.5
1   4.9 sepal.width 3.0
2   4.7 sepal.width 3.2
3   4.6 sepal.width 3.1
4   5.0 sepal.width 3.6

sns.lmplot(x ='sepal.length', y ='value', data = df,col='variable',
           col_wrap=2,aspect = 0.6, height,= 4, palette ='coolwarm')
```

[image]